# Using stack instead of queue in ThreadPoolExecutor

Tags: java, android, multithreading, threadpoolexecutor

I'm developing an android project which I want to implement a simple downloader. So I use a ThreadPool which implemented as below

```
private static final int MAX_QUEUE_SIZE = 200;

private static final int CPU_COUNT = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
private static final int CORE_POOL_SIZE = CPU_COUNT;
private static final int MAXIMUM_POOL_SIZE = CPU_COUNT;
private static final int KEEP_ALIVE = 10;
private static final BlockingQueue<Runnable> postThreadQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>(MAX_QUEUE_SIZE);


private ThreadPool()
{
    super(CORE_POOL_SIZE, MAXIMUM_POOL_SIZE, KEEP_ALIVE, TimeUnit.SECONDS, postThreadQueue, postThreadFactory);
}

private static final ThreadFactory postThreadFactory = new ThreadFactory()
{
    private final AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger(1);

    public Thread newThread(Runnable runnable)
    {
        return new Thread(runnable, "Post AsyncTask #" + counter.getAndIncrement());
    }
};
```

And it works fine. The problem is ThreadPoolExecuter using queue so last download takes too long to execute but I need to execute them faster (last downloads has more priority).

The question is this, How can I use stack instead of this BlockingQueue?

Thanks in advance